# Are the powers given by binder's vestiges passive?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am doing some research regarding binder class using the book Tome of Magic. After making a pact with vestige, (eg Naberius since I am going for Binder//Hellfire Warlock and need a vestige to heal my CON score every round) are the powers given by the vestige active 24/7 or do I need to perform some sort of action to activate the vestige powers every round?

These are the powers given by Naberius:
Disguise Self, Faster Ability Healing, Naberius’s Skills, Persuasive Words*, Silver Tongue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the particular ability.

> Whether the binding check succeeds or fails, you gain the powers granted by the vestige for 24 hours.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 10)</sup>

> #### Granted Abilities
>
> The supernatural abilities that the vestige grants are given in this element of its description. The following rules govern these supernatural abilities. [...]
>
> - Some of the supernatural abilities provided by vestiges provide constant benefit once activated. If the duration of a particular effect is not stated or implied by the ability description, assume it is constant. Typically, binders take a few moments to activate such abilities immediately after making a pact with a vestige. Most effects that are not constant can be used only once every 5 rounds (see the ability description for details).

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 19)</sup>

In the case of Naberius, the Grinning Hound, we have

> *Disguise Self:* You can alter the appearance of your form as a standard action. This effect works like the *disguise self* spell.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 41)</sup>

The *disguise self* spell has a duration, and so therefore does this ability.

> *Faster Ability Healing:* You heal 1 point in each damaged ability score every round, and 1 point in all drained ability scores every hour.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 41)</sup>

No mention of any kind of duration here, so this ability is constant for as long as you remain bound to Naberius.

> *Naberius’s Skills:* At the time you make your pact, you can choose a number of skills equal to your Constitution bonus (if any). Your choice must be skills that can’t be used untrained and in which you have no ranks. For the duration of the binding, you can make skill checks with your chosen skills even though you are untrained. If your Constitution modifier decreases after you make the pact, you lose the ability tomake untrained checks with an equal number of the chosen skills. Lost skills are chosen randomly, and they remain inaccessible to you until you make another pact with Naberius.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 42)</sup>

Has an explicit duration, but that duration is “the duration of the binding,” so it’s just as constant as any other ability.

> *Persuasive Words:* You can direct a verbal command at a single living target within 30 feet as if using the *command* spell. A successful Will save negates the effect. When your effective binder level reaches 14th, your words become even more persuasive and this ability functions like the *suggestion* spell. Once you have used this ability, you cannot do so again for 5 rounds.

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 42)</sup>

Both *command* and *suggestion* have durations, and therefore so does this. Also note the once-per-five-rounds thing mentioned in the vestige introduction.

> *Silver Tongue:* You can take 10 on Diplomacy and Bluff checks even if distracted or threatened. In addition, you can make a rushed Diplomacy check as a standard action and take no penalty. (Normally, a rushed Diplomacy check requires a full-round action and imposes a −10 penalty on the check.)

<sup>(*Tome of Magic* pg. 42)</sup>

No duration, so these effects are constant. (The effects of your Bluff and/or Diplomacy checks are as normal for those skills and depends how you use them.)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I think I am going for the warlock/binder hellfire warlock like you mentioned in the previous post. That seems to be best way to get most out of hellfire warlock without killing myself or spending ton of gold to purchase a wand that heals ability score.